# Segue from tableview to view controller

Tags: parsing, swift

I can't find where I haven't unwrapped my label so I can perform my segue. It keeps saying label doesn't have .text and fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I'm just trying to make the title of my view controller equal to the label text teamNameLabel

```
    import UIKit

class TimelineTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var timelineData:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(style: style)
        // Custom initialization
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    @IBAction func loadData(){
        timelineData.removeAllObjects()

        var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Sweets")

        findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in

            if error == nil{
                for object in objects{
                    let sweet:PFObject = object as PFObject
                    self.timelineData.addObject(sweet)
                }

                let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
                self.timelineData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.loadData()

        if PFUser.currentUser() == nil{
            var loginAlert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up / Login", message: "Please sign up or login", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            loginAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
                    textfield in
                    textfield.placeholder = "Your username"
                })

            loginAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({
                textfield in
                textfield.placeholder = "Your password"
                textfield.secureTextEntry = true
            })

            loginAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
                    alertAction in
                let textFields:NSArray = loginAlert.textFields! as NSArray
                let usernameTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(0) as UITextField
                let passwordTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(1) as UITextField

                PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTextfield.text, password: passwordTextfield.text){
                    (user:PFUser!, error:NSError!)->Void in
                    if user != nil{
                        println("Login successfull")
                    }else{
                        println("Login failed")
                    }


                }




                }))

            loginAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Up", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
                alertAction in
                let textFields:NSArray = loginAlert.textFields! as NSArray
                let usernameTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(0) as UITextField
                let passwordTextfield:UITextField = textFields.objectAtIndex(1) as UITextField

                var sweeter:PFUser = PFUser()
                sweeter.username = usernameTextfield.text
                sweeter.password = passwordTextfield.text

                sweeter.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock{
                    (success:Bool!, error:NSError!)->Void in
                    if error == nil{
                        println("Sign Up successfull")
                    }else{
                        let errorString = error.localizedDescription
                        println(errorString)
                    }


                }



                }))

            self.presentViewController(loginAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // #pragma mark - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return timelineData.count
    }


   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:SweetTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as SweetTableViewCell

        let sweet:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as PFObject

    cell.sweetTextView.alpha = 0
    cell.timestampLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.teamNameLabel.alpha = 0

        cell.sweetTextView.text = sweet.objectForKey("content") as String

        cell.teamNameLabel.text! = sweet.objectForKey("teamName") as String


        var dataFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dataFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        cell.timestampLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(sweet.createdAt)

        var findSweeter:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
        findSweeter.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: sweet.objectForKey("sweeter").objectId)

        findSweeter.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in
            if error == nil{
                let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser
                cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username


                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                        cell.sweetTextView.alpha = 1
                        cell.timestampLabel.alpha = 1
                        cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 1
                        cell.teamNameLabel.alpha = 1
                    })
            }
        }


        return cell
    }



    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if segue.identifier == "viewTeam" {

            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
                let vc = segue.destinationViewController as TeamViewController
                vc.title = timelineData[indexPath.row].teamNameLabel.text
            }

            /*
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController).topViewController as TeamViewController
            controller.title = timelineData[indexPath.row].teamNameLabel
            */

            //viewController.title = TimelineData.teamNameLabel.text
            //}
        }

    }
```

My problem is in my prepare segue message

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if segue.identifier == "viewTeam" {

            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
                let vc = segue.destinationViewController as TeamViewController
                vc.title = timelineData[indexPath.row].teamNameLabel.text
            }

            /*
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController).topViewController as TeamViewController
            controller.title = timelineData[indexPath.row].teamNameLabel
            */

            //viewController.title = TimelineData.teamNameLabel.text
            //}
        }

    }
```

Here is my cell class

```
    import UIKit

class SweetTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var usernameLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    @IBOutlet var timestampLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    @IBOutlet var teamNameLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    @IBOutlet var sweetTextView: UITextView! = UITextView()
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        //teamNameLabel.text = ""
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state

    }

}
```

This is driving me nuts

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that, in your prepareForSegue method, you are setting the title on the wrong instance of your view controller.

You create the variable `vc`, and set the title on it, but that does not change the destinationViewController instance.

Try this code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "viewTeam" {

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            (segue.destinationViewController as TeamViewController).title = timelineData[indexPath.row].teamNameLabel.text
        }

        /*
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController).topViewController as TeamViewController
        controller.title = timelineData[indexPath.row].teamNameLabel
        */

        //viewController.title = TimelineData.teamNameLabel.text
        //}
    }

}
```

Comment: That still didn't work.. it still says UILabel! does not have a member named text

Comment: ok so now I got it to recognize the text in the label with (segue.destinationViewController as TeamViewController).title = timelineData[indexPath.row].teamNameLabel!.text but now its saying its giving me an error Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code .. blah blah

Comment: Your output screen should have more info about exactly what your program is trying to but unable to do.

Comment: I just tried to print the variable to my output its printing nil. By using parse am I not setting the value of the label? My tableview is holding the label name but when I try to print its printing nil

Comment: I think its because I initialized my @IBOutlet teamNameLAbel in my cell class but how do I call it?

Answer (score 0):

ok I got it!!! Heres my segue

```
 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "viewTeam" {


        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            println(timelineData[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("teamName")) //.teamNameLabel?.text)

        (segue.destinationViewController as TeamViewController).title = timelineData[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("teamName")! as? String
        }

        /*

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as TeamViewController).topViewController as TeamViewController
        controller.title = timelineData[indexPath.row].teamNameLabel!.text
        */

        //viewController.title = TimelineData.teamNameLabel.text
        //}
    }

}
```